# how to create database to use it in wordpress website?

Tags: plugins, database

I install wordpress from wamp. 
My task is to create participants table which contain all participants in an event. I already create the event page in the website and add registration form to this page. Now, I want to store form data in a database. how to create this database and link it to the website?

Note: first when I install wamp I create test_db database. Is that database will contains all the tables in my website? if yes, how can I use the tables in some of the website pages?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate properly with Wordpress consider using Custom Post Types instead of creating tables in the database.
In your case you could have two new post types:
Events
Event participants

Here you can find more information about custom post types:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

This site is handy for generating the initial code that facilitates your new post type:
https://generatewp.com/post-type/

Alternatively if you're not comfortable with coding it you could try searching for an events registration plugin.